# SQL Server Migration, Left Outer Join, where to put the condition, ON or WHERE

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to migrate an old SQL Server 2000 DataBase, and I have to convert some queries, I found something really strange for me

Having this old query:

```
Select opo.opoId, fac.rate From 
t_Oportunities opo, t_factors fac
Where
opo.facId *= fac.facId
And opo.clientGroup = @Group
```

I migrated this way:

```
Select opo.opoId, fac.rate From 
t_Oportunities opo 
Left Outer Join t_factors fac ON opo.facId = fac.facId
WHERE opo.clientGroup = @Group
```

But the results where different than expected, less rows, so I tried this way:

```
Select opo.opoId, fac.rate From 
t_Oportunities opo 
Left Outer Join t_factors fac ON (opo.facId = fac.facId AND opo.clientGroup     
= @Group)
```

This worked as expected but it is a surprise for me to have to set a WHERE condition in the ON

Comment: This happens because the `where` clause applies to the whole resultset after the join is done and the rows that do not match are not returned. The condition on the `on` clause are applied only to the join between those tables and since it is a left join, when no matches are found it will still return the data from the left table with nulls from the respective right table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*=` used in SQL-Server... wow that is old...

as for the reason for your attempt excluding records, is that once you put a `WHERE`  clause on the "right" table in a `LEFT JOIN`, you're effectively making it an `INNER JOIN`, as NULL records are excluded.

You can leave it as you did it at the end, though the parenthesis around the two where clauses on the join aren't needed.